# MemSql leaf down on Single server Cluster

Tags: singlestore

I have a single server cluster installation of MemSQL on Ubuntu 14 LTS.
I am unable to connect to memsql on port 3306 but the cluster is running on port 9000.
Looks like a leaf is down. When i tried to upgrade memsql to version 4.0.1 I got this error:-

```
Starting MemSQL Upgrade
Currently on state OfflineClusterUpgrade.Init
Currently on state OfflineClusterUpgrade.SnapshottingDatabases
Currently on state OfflineClusterUpgrade.OfflineClusterUpgradeFail
MemSQL node 8D84F89D6716F03A44EACB9E3AF6565FA76B9DE9 failed to upgrade: Could not connect to MemSQL node 8D84F89D6716F03A44EACB9E3AF6565FA76B9DE9. Is the MemSQL node online?
```

What can I do to bring MemSql up again?

Comment: It shows Master Aggregator offline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cluster manager provided the help on port 9000.
Firstly it clearly showed the status of all nodes.

There was an alert icon clicking it showed the solution.

I ran the command

`memsql-ops cluster-start`

It caused the node to recover and start again. This is really good.

Comment: Glad you were able to start the cluster @user2146616 !