# memsql aggregator doesn't start on CentOS 6.7

Tags: singlestore

We're currently evaluating memsql and have two setups. One is running on CentOS 6.7, one on CentOS 7.1.

While using CentOS 7.1, after a system reboot the master has all services started, but the CentOS 6.7 variant does not and shows that the aggregator is offline. We had to run `memsql-ops cluster-start` found in [MemSql leaf down on Single server Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423480/memsql-leaf-down-on-single-server-cluster/35270224). We're wondering if this is related to the init.d/systemctl diffs on the machines. Any reply appreciated!

Cheers,
µatthias

Answer (score 0):

currently Ops only sets up a Sys-V style init script in /etc/init.d when it is installed by root. However, once Ops starts up correctly it should immediately check whether or not MemSQL is running.  If it is not running but it should be Ops will start the cluster automatically.  Can you confirm that you didn't run `memsql-ops cluster-stop` before shutting down the cluster?  If you do that, when Ops comes back up it will *not* start the MemSQL cluster.

Comment: thx4reply! I actually did not run the cluster-stop command. We just shut down the machine by using the aws cli.

Comment: When you start the machine after stopping it via the AWS cli, can you confirm that MemSQL Ops starts up?

Comment: memsql-ops comes up, but the memsqld service does not. I'll try to implement a stacktrace and come back to you soon.

Comment: update: actually we didn't found any solution for this. restarting the service manually (systemctl service restart) works for us as a workaround